# Total ordering for the Free Commutative Monoid on Infinite Elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, monoid

From what I can gather the Free Commutative Monoid on infinite elements is isomorphic to the Natural Numbers under multiplication. The generating set is the prime numbers and every element of $\mathbb{N}^\times$ is uniquely defined by its prime factorisation $\prod p_i^{k_i}$.

I understand how a Free Commutative Monoid admits a partial ordering. First powers of a prime are ordered e.g. $2^0 < 2^1 < 2^2 < etc...$. Then the primes form a finite countable set which can be iterated so $2 < 3 < 5 < 7$ etc. Then the product of any primes is less than those individual primes: $ p_1 p_2 > p_2 > p_1$ (assuming ordered primes).

But how do you get from the Free Commutative Monoid on infinite elements to the total ordering of the natural numbers? e.g. why is $7 < (8 = 2^3)$ in $\mathbb{N}^\times$?

Comment: You don't.  The total ordering of the natural numbers is a separate structure that they have.

Comment: @EricWofsey I was looking at this [Mathoverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/105851/strictly-totally-ordered-semigroups-looking-for-references) where the accepted answer says "semigroup is totally orderable iff torsion-free and cancellative". I believe the Free Commutative Monoid meets those requirements. Then shouldn't there be a procedure that defines the total ordering?

Comment: @TheCriticalImperitive A torsion-free and cancellative semigroup - like the one in your question - admits **at least one** ordering, but maybe more. A free commutative monoid on more than one generator will always admit **several** distinct orderings, so there's no way to recover any one in particular (without additional information of course).

Comment: @NoahSchweber OK that makes sense. You mentioned additional information - is there any particular information that would force a particular ordering?

Comment: @TheCriticalImperitive Having the additive structure as well would be enough, for example.

Comment: @NoahSchweber thinking about this some more, would existence of equivalence classes be enough here? If $N^\times$ is constructed gradually then the order that elements are added to the set is based on the equivalence classes they create. e.g. if the set starts as {1,2} then 4=2x2 can't be next because there are 2 equivalence classes mod 2. Every $m$th member creates the subset $mN^\times$ then $N/mN^\times$ is the equivalence classes mod m. The next member of $mN^\times$ can't be added to the set until $m$ other members have been added into its equivalence class. This would be a total order?